# Is there an appropraite rel attribute for a link to a category page?

Tags: html, web-standards

`the_category()` function in WordPress generates some invalid markup by creating an anchor tag with a rel attribute that looks like "category tag" (see the markup for the "Uncategorized" link [here](http://example.wordpress.com)).

It seems the problem is category is not a valid value, and also it should be one word.

Most people are deleting it completely, but I was looking at the [list of valid values](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values) and was wondering if any of them would be appropriate for a link to category page (such as [this one](http://example.wordpress.com/category/uncategorized/))?

In particular `tag`, `section`, and `subsection` caught my eye, but their intended uses are not clear to me.

Comment: I would just go with tag. Seems the most appropriate in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`category` and `tag` *are* valid values. Some validators are not up to date.

`tag` is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-tag) in the HTML5 spec.

`category` is listed at http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions, which is the [normative](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#other-link-types) registry for link type extensions.

If both link types apply, it's correct to separate them with whitespace.

Note: don't use these link types on *any* link to the category/tag page; only use it where the linking page is categorized/tagged with the corresponding category/tag. So a page listing all categories shouldn't use the `rel` value "`category`" for the links.